# Serializando e deserializando atributos com nomes diferentes dos campos Json

Tags: java, gson

Estou tendo a necessidade de serializar e deserializar um atributo que a sua referência no Json tenha um nome diferente. Por exemplo, no Json que estou recebendo há um campo `text` e gostaria que o valor desse atributo fosse preenchido em meu atributo chamado `descricao`.

Isso não aconteceria normalmente já que o framework Gson relaciona campos e atributos com nomes iguais, ou seja, o Gson vai procurar na minha classe Java um atributo `text` para inserir o valor do atributo `text` do Json, mas o meu caso é diferente.

Também questiono se é possível fazer o mesmo mas quando for serializar um objeto, por exemplo pegando o valor que há no campo `descricao` e inserindo em um elemento `text` do Json.

Tudo isso é possível? Se sim, como isso poderia ser feito?

Comment: Considere adicionar quebras de linha na sua pergunta para facilitar a leitura.

Comment: Quebras de linhas adicionadas, @lazyFox. Obrigado pela sugestão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É bem simples, basta utilizarmos uma *annotation*, mas primeiro vamos visualizar o problema com um exemplo:

```
{
    "arrayInteger": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ],
    "boolean": true,
    "nullObject": null,
    "number": 123,
    "text": "Hello World"
}
```

Note que ele não é compatível com o objeto abaixo devido a diferença de nome dos campos `text` e `descricao`, o que fará o campo `descricao` ficar `null` após a deserialização:

```
public class Objeto {
    private int[] array;
    private Boolean boolean;
    private Object nullObject;
    private String descricao;
}
```

Para resolver isso, existe uma anotação chamada `@Serialize(“NOME_DO_CAMPO”)`, onde passamos o nome do campo referente no Json, **tanto para serialização quanto para deserialização**. No caso, seria simplesmente isso:

```
public class Objeto {
    private int[] array;
    private Boolean boolean;
    private Object nullObject;
    @Serialize("text")
    private String descricao;
}
```

Após adicionarmos essa notação, tanto serializações quanto deserializações  estarão ligando `text` a `descricao`.